# Local storage not deleting data until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, dom

I am pretty much new to Javascript and working on this simple ToDo app that uses local storage to persist data. However, the Delete function can only delete from local storage when refreshed the page. What could be causing this bug? I have attached my code below

I tried commenting on the e.preventDefault() on the form but the page kept on reloading when a task is submitted.

```
// Selectors
const ul = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const todoContainer = document.querySelector('.todo-container');
const clearButton = document.createElement('button');
clearButton.classList.add('clear-button');
clearButton.textContent = 'Clear all Completed';
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');

let todoTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
let id = todoTasks.length + 1;

const createElement = ({ description, completed = true, index }) => {
  const todoItem = document.createElement('li');
  todoItem.classList.add('todo-list-item');
  todoItem.setAttribute('id', index);
  todoItem.innerHTML = `
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="${completed}">
    <button class="hidden" name="${index}"></button>
    <span class="todo-item">${description}</span>
     <button name='eclips'><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
     <button name='delete'><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    `;
  ul.appendChild(todoItem);
  todoContainer.appendChild(ul);
  todoContainer.appendChild(clearButton);
};
// get each todo task
todoTasks.forEach(createElement);

// Function that add todo
const addTask = (description, completed, ind) => {
  const input = taskInput.value;
  todoTasks.push({
    description: input,
    completed: false,
    index: ind,
  });
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoTasks));
  return { description, completed, ind };
};

const checkTodo = (e) => {
  const lineText = e.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
  if (lineText.style.textDecoration === 'line-through') {
    lineText.style.textDecoration = 'none';
  } else {
    lineText.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    lineText.classList.toggle('completed');
  }
};

// Function that delete todo

const handleDeleteAndCheck = (e) => {
  const item = e.target;
  if (e.target.classList[1] === 'fa-trash') {
    const todo = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    const targetId = item.parentElement.parentElement.id;
    todoTasks = todoTasks.filter((task) => task.index !== +targetId);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoTasks));
    todo.remove();
  }
  if (e.target.classList === 'check') {
    checkTodo();
  }
};

// Function that Edit todo

const editTask = (e) => {
  const item = e.target;
  if (item.classList[0] === 'todo-item') {
    item.contentEditable = true;
    item.style.display = 'block';
  }
};

const check = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-check-square');
const index = document.querySelectorAll('#index');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const input = taskInput.value;
  const checkValue = check.value;
  // const indexValue = index.value;
  const newTask = addTask(input, checkValue, id);
  createElement(newTask);
  // location.reload();
  taskInput.value = '';
  id += 1;
});

ul.addEventListener('click', handleDeleteAndCheck);

ul.addEventListener('click', editTask);
```

Comment: You are deleting the data from localStorage but that doesn't change your current DOM, execute `todoTasks.forEach(createElement);` after having deleted one to "refresh" your page's content

Answer (score 0):

Here please change the statement with this in your **handleDeleteAndCheck()** method. It will remove the local storage at that time.

localStorage.removeItem('todo');